# Unity in-game render problem (blurry), see GIF

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, blurry

My game looks kinda blurry, when I move and stand still, the camera slowly follows my character and the rendering looks blurry. I created a GIF:
I found nothing, how to solve this problem.

https://gyazo.com/240018fc1269a8d9ad7b914881db8cd7

Comment: in editor only or also in the standalone player for example?

Comment: When you try to move by half pixels in a pixel perfect setup things like this tend to happen.

Comment: I don't know, how can I try this. This is my first attempt to make an 2D-Game. The worst thing is the rendering of the environment, not the player!

Comment: How can I change this with the pixels, so it doesn't look this whack. Sorry, I'm an absolutely newbie at unity and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Unity's 2D Pixel Perfect Package.
Here is a [Unity's blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/es/2019/03/13/2d-pixel-perfect-how-to-set-up-your-unity-project-for-retro-8-bits-games/) explaining how to import it and use it.

Comment: Tank you, now it's nearly perfect.